# Android Popup Window with Variable Text

Tags: java, android, android-popupwindow

So having a bit of trouble with a popup box, new to android and not sure how to go about this. I would like to have a popup that displays specific text based on a public variable, so when the button is clicked, the variable is checked, and depending on what that variable is the appropriate text is displayed in the textView.

- Is is possible to create string variables, and with a series of if statements pass those variables to the textView?
- Do I need individual layout files for each one and use the if statements to determine what view will be be passed and popped up?

popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Close"
            android:id="@+id/button1"/>     

</LinearLayout>
```

mainActivity.java

```
 Button pubtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.popupOpen);
 pubtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  

    View puView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);  
    PopupWindow puWindow = new PopupWindow(
               puView, 
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
               LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  

             Button btnExit = (Button)puView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
             btnExit.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
      puWindow.dismiss();
     }});
             puWindow.showAsDropDown(pubtn, 0, 0);  
   }});
```

any help or direction on how to go about this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this example:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) YourActivity.this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_xml,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
    popupWindow = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 190, true);

    popupText = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.popupText);
    popupText.setText(yourString);
```

Comment: Brilliant! So simple, not sure why I didn't think of that.

Comment: One more thing, I saw in API 21 you cannot close the popup, so you should add this:         popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());